# ConcurrentModificationError in static synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrentmodification

I have a class which contains a field and two `static synchronized` methods. The field is a map whose key is an integer and value is a list. One of the methods is used to add a new item in the list and the other one is used to read all the items in the list. I have multiple threads to read and write the `map`. I eliminate some details in the code so let's assume the key is always in the map.

To my understanding, only one thread can enter either `write` or `read` at the same time because both of them are declared as `static synchronized`. That means when one thread is writing something, the other threads cannot write or read, and vice versa. But why there is a `ConcurrentModificationError` thrown by the iterator iterating on the list return by `map.get(i)` at line `for(int item: map.get(i))`? Can anyone explain what's the reason? Thanks in advance!

```
class A {
   private static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map;

   public static synchronized void write(int i, int item) {
      map.get(i).add(item);
   }

   public static synchronized void read(int i) {
      for(int item: map.get(i)) System.out.println(item);
   }
}
```

Comment: There are a few possibilities: you are updating map somewhere directly, without using the read/write methods, or you're updating one of the lists in the map without using the read/write methods.

Comment: You said, "I eliminate some details..." Are you sure that no other code anywhere else in your program could get hold of one of those lists and modify it concurrently with the `A.read(i)` call? Your example doesn't show any way for that to happen, but then your example also does not show how the lists get created....

Answer (score 1):

I think, somewhere in your code, there is a concurrent modification of the list held by the map. I wrote a small code which throws the same ConcurrentModificationException:

```
public class A {
    private static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static synchronized void write(int i, int item) {
        if (map.containsKey(i))
            map.get(i).add(item);
        else {
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(item);
            map.put(i, list);
        }
    }

    public static synchronized void read(int i) {
        for (int item : map.get(i))
            System.out.println(item);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable writeAction = () -> A.write(1, 1);
        Runnable readAction = () -> A.read(1);
        Runnable modifyAction = () -> A.modifyList(1, 2);

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000; i++) {
            service.execute(writeAction);
            service.execute(readAction);
            service.execute(modifyAction);
        }

        service.shutdown();
    }

    /**
     * not synchronized
     * @param i
     * @param item
     */
    public static void modifyList(int i, int item) {
        if (map.containsKey(i))
            map.get(i).add(item);
        else {
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(item);
            map.put(i, list);
        }
    }

}
```

This code definitely throws the exception when two threads in the pool are running the modifyList() and read() method concurrently.

So either there is a method in your class which is not synchronized or maybe some getter which returns the ref of the original list and not copy of it (I mean escaping reference) and whichever method it is returned to - they are modifying the list and concurrently.

Comment: A very interesting question for me, since I am just learning concurrency. Please drop the issue if you find it :) Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your example! But it turns out the problem can be solved by Collections.synchronizedMap(map). I don't understand why my previous code cannot guarantee thread safety on the list in the map. Is my understanding on static synchronized wrong?

Comment: No your understanding is not wrong I think. static methods are bound to the class and when you sync it is as good as sync(ClassName.class) which is a class level lock. Both your ops are synchronised and making the map synchronised makes it work, so I still thinkm either there is an escaping reference or some other method operatiin on the the map without sync.

Comment: Thanks Priyak! So if I have 2 static synchronized methods in class A. One is "static synchronized void foo() { too(A.map); }" and the other is "static synchronized too(Map map) { do something on the map }". Would it be a concern?